# how to show the files thumbnails like windows explorer in delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I use the `TFileListBox` control to show lists of files. But I wonder how to show the file thumbnails in the same way that Windows Explorer does?

Comment: You really need a real control. Like a list view. You could use a shell aware list view.

Comment: @David, OT: are the `ShellControls` still distributed (with the D2010) ? It was somewhere in the `Demos` path I think. Anyway I guess they don't support thumbnails.

Comment: @TLama I think ShellControls are still around. I've used ShellShock in the past.

Comment: I can not find the shellconrols in delphi 2010... any other clue ?

Comment: The shell controls are in Delphi 2010. Use Start->All Programs, navigate to the RAD Studio or Delphi 2010 item, expand it, and choose `Demos`. It's in the Win32 folder under `DelphiWin32\VCLWin32\ShellControls`. Open and build the `vclshlctrls.dproj` first, and then build and install the `dclshlctrls.dproj`. You'll need to add the folder above to your Project->Options in the search path for the compiler to be able to find them.

Comment: @Ken: I didn't find the ShellControls... The only things I find are --- Delphi 2010/Delphi Distiller/Modify, Repair, Uninstall/RAD Studio Command Prompt/RAD Studio Documentation/Uninstall/XML Mapper ---  And as for the the DelphiWin32\ I did not find the folder "VCLWin32/ShellControls" the only subfolders I find in DelphiWin32 are --- MDIApp / SDIApp / Win2kApp --- any clue how to find it ?  And for the TOpenPictureDialog, I did not use them because I want to make my own WinExplorer like Windows made... :P For the TFileListBox, I'm still a beginner in Delphi... Need lots to learn.... LOL... :)

Comment: I installed Delphi 2010 on my `D:` drive, starting in the `D:\RAD Studio` folder, and the Demos ended up in `D:\RAD Studio\7.0\Demos\DelphiWin32\VCLWin32\ShellControls`. If you don't have them in the similar location on your machine, perhaps you didn't install the demos? (I'm not sure where they end up in a default install, as I don't install the IDEs in `C:\Program Files (x86)` on Win7. I install on another drive altogether.)

Comment: In my Start menu (Win7), I have `Embarcadero RAD Studio 2010`, with `C++ Builder 2010`, `Check for Updates`, `Delphi 2010`, `Demos`, `Embarcadero RAD Studio`, `Modify, Repair, Uninstall`, `RAD Studio Command Prompt`, and `RAD Studio Documentation`. I don't know why your Start Menu looks like it does; I'd suspect choices made during the installation. You can do a repair install to add items you chose not to install initially (which might include the demos).

Comment: BTW, `embarcadero` and `borland` are not necessary in your tags, as `Delphi` was developed by them. The company names are meaningless, just like using `microsoft` for a question about `Visual Studio` would be - there's no other `Visual Studio` maker, and there's no other `Delphi` IDE maker.

Comment: @Ken : Thanks for the demos guidance :) And also thanks for telling me about the tag :)

Comment: Anyway why I cannot build the vclshlctrls.dproj ? it said "Cannot run project unless a host application is defined. Use the Run|Parameter... dialog box..."  how to fix this ?

Comment: @Ken : OK, I manage to build it, but not compile it...

Comment: Right-click on the project in the `Project Manager` and choose `Install` from the popup (context) menu. The `Project Manager` in the default configuration is the area on the right edge of the screen that displays the files in the project. You need to build the `vclshlctrls` first, and then install the `dclshlctrls`, which is the design-time package. (If you need more info, it should probably be a new question about installing the `ShellControls` into the IDE.)

Comment: @KenWhite - also, `borland`, `inprise`, `codegear`, `embarcadero` :-)

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera: Yes, I know. I didn't see a point in listing them, as they're not important either. There's only one Delphi IDE, regardless of who currently owns the name. It's still the same product, just like Visual Studio is the same product. I didn't think the extra noise was important - Sidhi got the point I was making. :) The manufacturer/publisher/owner name isn't needed in the tags when the product is distinctive. You don't need `Chevy` in the tags when you're talking about cars and someone mentions `Corvette` or `Camaro`.

Comment: @KenWhite - agree, just adding that for sake of completeness. And in jest, of course.

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera - I caught the jest. See the smiley in my comment? :)

Comment: @KenWhite : GREAT !!! everything is working up just fine :) Thanks for the help :) BTW how can I make this question as answered by you-KenWhite ? :)

Comment: Iv'e posted an answer with the suggestion, along with the steps to install in Delphi 2010. Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try using the `ShellControls` components included in Delphi. (Note that David Heffernan sort of mentioned, and TLama made the initial specific suggestion in the first two comments to your question.) They're not installed by default in recent versions, so you'll have to install them yourself.

These instructions are for the version of Delphi you've indicated you're using (Delphi 2010) - they're the same basically for `XE/XE2`, except they're in the `Samples\Delphi\VCL\ShellControls` folder instead (and the `Start` entry contains `XE` or `XE2` instead of `2010`, of course).

Use `Start->All Programs`, navigate to the `Embarcadero RAD Studio` or `Embarcadero Delphi 2010` item, expand it, and choose `Demos`. It's in the `Win32` folder under `DelphiWin32\VCLWin32\ShellControls`. Open and build the `vclshlctrls.dproj` first, and then build and install the `dclshlctrls.dproj`. You'll need to add the folder above to your `Project->Options` in the search path for the compiler to be able to find them.

To install the components after building the second package, right-click on the project in the 'Project Manager' and choose 'Install' from the popup (context) menu. The 'Project Manager' in the default configuration is the area on the right edge of the screen that displays the files in the project. Remember, you need to build `vclshlctrls` first, and then install `dclshlctrls`, which is the design-time package.

You should then find the `TShellListView`, `TShellTreeView`, `TShellComboBox`, and `TShellChangeNotifier` components on your palette in the `Samples` category.

Comment: @Ken, actually it was me who mentioned `ShellControls` with note that they have no thumbnail support. So, do they support thumbnails (I can't check that now but as I remember they don't) ?

Comment: if ShellControls do not support thumbnail view, then this answer is incorrect.

Comment: ShellControls do not support thumbnail view with Delphi 2010.  Do ShellControls support thumbnails in Delphi XE2?

Comment: @TLama: You're right. David mentioned a "shell aware list view", but you were the first to specifically mention the ShellControls. Corrected. AFA whether the ShellControls support thumbnails or not, I have no idea (I haven't had time to check). If you read the comments to the original question, Sidhi asked me to post these directions (first provided in those comments) as an answer to the question, and I did so. Since it was accepted, it must be what the asker wanted. kobik: Read the las sentence I wrote before your name - if the asker says it's the answer they wanted, it's not incorrect. :)

Comment: @Ken, I never read the comments, I looked at the question title which says: `how to show the files thumbnails like windows explorer in delphi?`. but if OP is happy with this, me happy too... :)

Answer (score 0):

.thumb files are ordinary png files, just with a different file suffix.
Knowing this one can display them in a TImage.

First the .thumb extension needs to be registered as new file format.
For this include PngImage in your uses and call this:

```
MyImage.Picture.RegisterFileFormat('thumb', 'PNG based thumbnails', TPngImage);
```

Later you can display the thumb file you like like this:

```
MyImage.Picture.LoadFromFile('d:\Pictures\Pictures.thumb');
```